# How to log individual test times in maven surefire

Tags: maven, testing, logging, time, surefire

I have a project with many modules, and I'd like to know how long each test takes to execute. 
Is there any parameter that can output that information? I've searched online and found nothing.

I could run all the test cases on the ide, which logs the execution times, and copy the times to a file, but I don't wanna do this every time I want the tests time log.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `target/surefire-reports` directory.  Each project includes a report for each test it runs, and the reports contain test execution times.

Comment: Is there a way I can view the summary of the execution times of all the tests in a single file?